# Unable to print "Unknown" if a AWS instance is not having a name tag associated using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto

Below is a little code snippet of a program i wrote which gets all instance ip and instance tags associated with it. I can easily do this using boto , my problem is if i find a AWS instance which is not having any tag name associated with it i want to display/write in file "ip UNKNOWN".

```
for reservation in reservations: 
  for instances in reservation.instances: 
    if instances.state == "running": 
     print instances.private_ip_address,instances.tags['Name'] 
     fileCSV.write("%s %s\n"%(instances.private_ip_address,instances.tags['Name'])) 
    if instances.state == "running" and 'Name' in instances.tags==' ': 
     print "%s %s" % (instances.private_ip_address,"UNKNOWN") 
     fileCSV.write("%s %s\n"%(instances.private_ip_address,"UNKNOWN")
```

This code prints something like this

```
192.124.121.17
192.124.121.11 squid-server
192.124.121.13 apache
```

I am expecting :

```
192.124.121.17 UNKNOWN
192.124.121.11 squid-server
192.124.121.13 apache
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code always catches the first `if` block.

You can try use the `default value` dictionary option in the `get` method.

Try this:

```
for reservation in reservations: 
  for instances in reservation.instances: 
    if instances.state == "running": 
        name = instances.tags["Name"] if instances.tags["Name"] != "" else "UNKNOWN"
        print instances.private_ip_address,name
        fileCSV.write("%s %s\n" % (instances.private_ip_address,name))
```

Comment: This doesn't work,still I am  getting the same output

Comment: okay.. this works and prints the list as expected.. but when i try to write it to file it gives a syntax error at end of line. I am confused coz the error points at blank line

Comment: Oh, I forget to close the `write` function. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks.. I got it too.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this, but this should work.

```
for reservation in reservations: 
  for instances in reservation.instances: 
    if instances.state == "running": 
     print instances.private_ip_address, instances.tags['Name'] if instances.tags['Name'] else 'UNKNOWN'
```

Comment: @DeepaliMittal try now. Looks like 'Name' always exists in tags.